# Compatibility of modern shutter release cable with vintage Kodak No 1

Tags: shutter-release, vintage, kodak

I've inherited a vintage "No. 1 Pocket Kodak", a medium format folder from somewhere around 1930. The existing shutter release cable no longer works, as the braiding has split and the spring inside slips through the gap.

Is a modern mechanical shutter release cable likely to fit?

The shutter comes with a short mechanical cable release that screws in next to the shutter lever. It seems to work in the conventional way by just pushing a rod/pin down into the shutter mechanism. I'm afraid I can't accurately measure the thread, but the diameter of the whole screw is pretty small, about 2 or 3 mm.

Other features of the camera are still compatible with modern kit, for example the tripod mounts accept a modern tripod and it uses 120 film.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out yes, a modern mechanical shutter release cable is compatible with the No 1 Pocket Kodak.

I bought a 40cm "hähnel" cable from a local camera store in London and it fits. The new cable has a longer threaded section, and with a more noticeable taper than the original, but it screwed in without any excessive force and triggered the shutter with no problems.

[image: The original and new cable threaded sections]
[image: No 1 pocket kodak with modern shutter release cable]